# Deadlock inserting into a table in SQLServer 2012 (10.50.6000.34)

Tags: sql-server, multithreading

I have a problem with a SQL Server where I change the requests to multithreaded and it executes this stored procedure on multiple connections to the database and results in a deadlock.   I can't imagine how it is deadlocking.  If I do it single threaded it runs fine.  At one point (when I first wrote this), it worked inserting 22,000 records without a deadlock (table was empty, so no updates in that situation)  The code looks like this:

```
Create Procedure InsertUpdateRecord
  @Email varchar(255),
  @State Varchar(50)   -- Other parameters, shouldn't matter
as
 Begin
 if (not exists (select * from [MyTable] WITH (NOLOCK) where email=@email))
     begin
     insert into [MyTable] (email, state) values (@email, @state)
     end
 else
     begin
     update [MyTable] set state=@state where email=@email
     end
 end
 end
```

Pretty simple, and I don't see any way it could be doing anything other than simple row locking on the unique column 'email', and I don't see any way it could create a deadlock.  Can someone explain this and offer a solution?

Comment: Can you provide us with an execution plan and or more information about the indexes on the [MyTable] if any?

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical case where you should consider `UPDLOCK` in your query:

```
begin tran
if exists (select * from table with (updlock,serializable) where key = @key)
begin
   update table set ...
   where key = @key
end
else
begin
   insert into table (key, ...)
   values (@key, ...)
end
commit tran
```

The `UPDLOCK` will already claim a lock if you hit your record with your first select and avoid the case of several methods trying to claim the same lock.
The `serializable` is used for:

- Statements cannot read data that has been modified but not yet
  committed by other transactions.
- No other transactions can modify data that has been read by the
  current transaction until the current transaction completes.
- Other transactions cannot insert new rows with key values that would
  fall in the range of keys read by any statements in the current
  transaction until the current transaction completes.

Just for completeness, your table is properly indexed and isn't a Heap, right?

Also, if not present, try to add an index to your `MyTable`:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyTable_email] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [email] ASC
)
```

You could also go ahead and enable the following trace flags:

```
DBCC TRACEON (1204,-1) 

DBCC TRACEON (1222,-1)
```

This won't stop the deadlocks, but will provide more details about them in your SQL Server log. It'll tell you what locks your transactions are trying to claim and who was currently owning that lock.

Comment: Tried that change, still getting deadlocks.  I don't understand how it is even possible to get a deadlock in this situation, both connections are requesting whatever locks in the exact same order, so there is no possible way to create a deadlock unless SQL is doing something really crazy.  Can someone explain what locks are created on the select (row?), update (row?), and insert (row?)  - all of which would be unique rows so zero conflicts.  If it was all table locks, still no deadlocks as everyone is locking the tables.

Comment: Do you have indexes on your table?

Comment: @TraderhutGames Updated my answer. Please provide more details about the table in question, but if there's no index present on email, that might be a good way to start.

Comment: It appears that there was a missing index on the email.  (There were two tables that were failing, both of which were missing an index.  I fixed the wrong one and retested :-(   So, that makes some sense now, I presume that it was doing table locks everywhere, but that still doesn't explain to me how it could deadlock.)

Comment: Adding the Index reduced the chance of a Deadlock to a HUGE level, instead of getting one within the first 90 records, I got to 270,000 before it deadlocked.  (This makes sense as the if() executed WAY faster without having to do a full table scan)  But sadly, I can't use this solution yet as I still get deadlocked.  I'll try the traceon to see what that yields.   Where do I fetch the results of that?

Comment: BTW: I was running 100 connections at the same to get the deadlock, but if I ran 2, it could clearly happen if it can happen with 100.  And the code for that just did the if (not exists(..)) insert into (...) - with no else, so just the if and the insert is enough to cause problems!    Not sure about 'isn't a Heap', but I don't think so just a normal table. (not sure how a heap works in SQL - a memory table?  Does SQL 2012 have those?)

Comment: A heap table is a table without a Clustered index. You can check your indexes on your table to figure this out. The result of your traceon can be found in your SQL Server logs, accessable through the SSMS. Once a deadlock occurs it will provide detailed logging giving us some more insight where exactly the deadlock occurs. If any, I would advise you to keep using the index. It's key if you want to keep a stable solution. Also, use the `UPDLOCK` in your if. It will immediately claim an update lock if your email was found, forcing a similar update to wait it's turn.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code from

```
if exists (select * from table where key = @key)
```

To

```
if exists (select 1 from table where key = @key)
```

This is more efficient

Also follow these common practices oo help minimize deadlocks:
Access objects in the same order.
Avoid user interaction in transactions.
Keep transactions short and in one batch.
Use a lower isolation level.
Use a row versioning-based isolation level.
Use bound connections.

As spelled out in detail here:  [Minimize Deadlocks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191242(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: This is actually - no longer? - true: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/26/sql-server-select-1-vs-select-an-interesting-observation/ It's something which was always told to me in the past as well, but apparently false.

Comment: This is his final words in the blog "I have been using SELECT 1 instead of SELECT * when checking existence of rows. I would like to see what my readers have an opinion about this. Please have your opinion and make your comment here."

Comment: Just to be clear, so have I. But The effects are very marginal at best, it would seem. I would be VERY surprised if this would be the reason for his deadlocking.

Comment: I did not say it was.  But when deadlocking is happening, any improvement you can make to performance is beneficial.

Comment: In terms of accessing the objects in the same order, what you see is what you get:  I'm only accessing a single table.   Select 1 vs Select * - shouldn't matter if I'm pulling data from the row or using 1, but noted for performance,  Not using transactions at all (would that help??)   What is lower isolation level than NOLOCK?   The bound connections might work, but seems like a massive overkill and will make code support more of a mess going forward

Comment: Based on the code you have, there is no smoking gun I can see that is 100% causing the deadlocks.  ( Which is why I provided what I did )